# Resolve "IS A" relationship with graphql-sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, graphql-js, graphql-sequelize

I'm using [`graphql`](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js), [`sequelize`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize) and [`graphql-sequelize`](https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize), and I'm having some troubles to resolve a ["IS A"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship.

My sequelize models are the following:

```js
// models.js

// User table
let User = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: Sequelize.INTEGER
    name: Sequelize.STRING
});

// Patient table
let Patient = sequelize.define('patient', {
    bloodType: Sequelize.STRING
});
// Defines "IS A" relationship: [Patient] IS A [User]
Patient.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'id',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    foreignKeyConstraint: true
})

// Doctor table
let Doctor = sequelize.define('doctor', {
  registry: Sequelize.STRING
});
// Defines "IS A" relationship: [Doctor] IS A [User]
Doctor.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'id',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    foreignKeyConstraint: true
})
```

And this is my graphql schema:

```js
// graphql.js
import resolver from 'graphql-sequelize';
import * as models from './models';

let userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    fields: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
        name: { type: GraphQLString }
    }
});

let patientType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Patient',
    fields: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
        bloodType: { type: GraphQLString },
        user: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(userType),
            // IMPORTANT!
            // How can I call resolver if I don't have a assotiation property like Patient.User?
            resolve: resolver()
        }
    }
});

// [doctorType omitted]

let schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: {
        users: {
            type: userType,
            resolve: resolver(models.User)
        },
        patients: {
            type: patientType,
            resolve: resolver(models.Patient)
        }
        // [doctor field omitted]
    }
  })
});
```

Calling the `resolver` method on the fields of the schema (`users` and `patients`) works fine, but my question is how to call resolver in the `patientType` to return its user since I don't have an association property.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by mickhansen on this [issue](https://github.com/mickhansen/graphql-sequelize/issues/209), all sequelize association calls return an association reference.

I stored the reference returned from `belongsTo`, as shown above:

```
 models.Patient.User = Patient.belongsTo(models.User, {
    foreignKey: {
      name: 'id',
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    foreignKeyConstraint: true
})
```

And then used it at the `resolve` function:

```
import * as models from '../path/models'

let patientType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Patient',
    fields: {
        id: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLInt) },
        bloodType: { type: GraphQLString },
        user: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(userType),
            resolve: resolver(models.default.Patient.User)
            // alternatively you could the following as sequelize always stores assotiations in associations
            // resolve: resolver(models.default.Patient.associations.User)
        }
    }
});
```